# Exposing message queues remotely with NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, polling

I have a scenario where I need to expose a bunch of event messages that have been created in NServiceBus to third parties over a simple authenticated REST API. The third party may or may not be using .NET (and they might even be JavaScript in the browser).

I understand that that pub/sub is a push mechanism, but I'm looking for a polling mechanism. Is this even possible in NServiceBus? Is this what an adapter is for, or is that for accepting inbound messages?

Comment: I am looking for some thing like this. I would like to know how to do this. Please this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration . I would like to keep all http request in a queue and then process so that all the request served.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would not want to expose your service bus to third parties.  You could manage to have some transport deliver to subscribers but then you would be sending an internal structure to the outside world.  You also did mention that you need a pull mechanism via a REST interface.

What I would suggest is to have a subscriber within your service bus that listens to the relevant messages and then either saves them in a serialized form in a type of 'event store' or de-normalizes them into the resources that the REST interface would expose.  These messages/resources would contain the relevant date/time stamp.

It would be up to the consumer of the REST API to specify some point in time to retrieve the resources from.  So the third party would simply keep track of when last they retrieved the data.  Of course they could retrieve as much as they need and new 'subscribers' would be able to retrieve the entire history if required.  Each message/resource should also have a GUID of sorts to be able to aid idempotence.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Publish event -> subscription -> store. Rest -> store. Nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Eben Please see this question. Thanks for help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration